# How to get lists from mailchimp based on apikey which is stored in database against userid

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to get lists from mailchimp based on apikey which is stored in database against user_id. I am getting all the lists based in apikey which is stored in my config file in laravel. But here i want to get lists from mailchimp based on api key stored in database.

The code I am using to get all the lists based on apikey from config file is:

```
public function getLists(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->id;
    $result = MailchimpFacade::request( 'lists', ['fields' => 'lists.id,lists.name'] );
    $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Lists appear successfully!', 'dataArray' => $result];
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

Here i want to get lists from mailchimp based on apikey stored in database.
You time and help will be highly appreciated!

```
public function getLists (Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->id;
    $mc = new MailChimp($request->input('api_key'));
    $result = $mc->get('/ping');
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($result, 200);
}

<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\APIKEY;
    use DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

    class ApiController extends Controller
    {
        public function getLists (Request $request)
        {
            $request->user()->id;
            $mc = new MailChimp($request->input('api_key'));
            $result = $mc->get('/ping');

            return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($result, 200);
        }
    }



                      public function getLists(Request $request)
{
     Auth::user()->id;
        $apikey = $request->input('api_key');
        DB::table('apikey')
        ->where('api_key','=', $apikey)
     ->get();
    if($apikey){
        $mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
        $mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('lists',['fields' => 'lists.id,lists.name'] );
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($mailchimp_ping, 200);

    }
    else
    {        $errorResponse = [
            'message' => 'Lists not found!',
            'error' => '401'
        ];
        return Response::json( $errorResponse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp` instead of `Facade`.

```
use DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
$result = $mc->get('lists');

print_r($result);
```

Full Controller, Edit it according to your need-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticateApiKey()
    {
        $mc = new MailChimp('48cda414960152d55f97a8f44e28ea20-us17');
        $mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('lists');
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($mailchimp_ping, 200);
    }
}
```

See [this](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) for further details.

Comment: Its returning empty lists

Comment: try `$result = $mc->get('/ping');`

Comment: "health_status": "Everything's Chimpy!"    its showing me this ,, but i want to see my lists details

Comment: i share my full controller with you

Comment: i don't see anything complete here?. where is your controller name, namespace??

Comment: public function getLists (Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->id;
    $mc = new MailChimp($request->input('api_key'));
    $result = $mc->get('/ping');

    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($result, 200);
}

Comment: i can't help you with this, update your code with complete controller, with name, namespace, use of other package everything, do you get it??

Comment: what is your controller name here?? Can't you just copy and paste??

Comment: and what is your apikey??

Comment: api_key =48cda414960152d55f97a8f44e28ea20-us17

Comment: @shahzad1122 that's it for you, try it

Comment: I dont want to hard code my api_key i wan to get it from database thanks for the help but i dont want to hard code my this key.

Comment: replace it with your database api key

Comment: @shahzad1122 make it accepted answer as it has solved your problem, right??

Comment: as i integrate mailchimp api and get the lists aagainst this apikey now i wan to mov to aweber api i want authenticate email address and password and if its authenticated we will get the mail lists after authenticated can u please refer me any useful link your help will be appreciated @Sohel0415

Comment: see the github link of that package i have added in my answer, that will help you

Comment: there is a link on my answer, follow that link

Comment: its  link of mailchimp api

Comment: yes, api describes everything, and for other parts, make a team to work, discuss with others about logic

Comment: thanks for your kind response ! i want to ask i have asked question with u yesterday that i want to get lists based on api key stored in database. here is little change ! i am using postman and i am giving url parameter api_key is equal to my key value and my url is something like http://api/getlists and with this url i am passing parameter apikey value now here i dont want to pass api key i just want to hit url and lists should be shown of logged in user.

Comment: i have shared my conroller with you

Comment: this function is binding me that you have to pass api_key value

Comment: if i dont want to pass apikey value and i just want to get lists by just hitting the url and that url will belong the user which is currently logged in is there anyway wothout passing the apikey value and i just find my lists details by doing that

Comment: i don't think you can do so

Comment: thanks for your kind response ! i am integrating aweber in my application the link which u have shared with me its totally different from aweber api can u please refer me any other useful link or something which can help me thanks

Comment: you can see this https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library though i am not sure what exactly you are looking for. Google it, consult with your colleagues, may be this way you can work around.

Comment: i want same functionality store the keys into databse and get the listing based on these keys. Thanks for your kind response i have a good collegeue on stack like u :) thanks for coperation

Comment: public function getLists(Request $request)
    {
         $request->user()->id;
            $apikey = DB::table('apikey')->select('api_key')->get();

            if($apikey){
            $mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
            $mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('lists',['fields' => 'lists.id,lists.name'] );
            return Response::json($mailchimp_ping, 200);

        }

Comment: I am trying to get lists without passing api_key parameter and i have made a query to get api_key value from database but its displaying output (false)

Comment: any solution of it please